# Greater than and less than characters on a TKL keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, powertoys

I just bought a CEPTER COSMO TKL keyboard, and I cannot figure out how I can produce the greater than and less than characters. I am on Windows 10.

The characters are on the keyboard as you can se from the photo. Those two keys pressed produces . and , - whereas they produce : and ; with shift pressed - Alt-Gr does not work, it produces no character, also tried different combinations of ctrl+alt+shift, with no success. I downloaded Powertoys and was able to map Alt-Gr to < but the greater than symbol is not in the character list in powertoys. Any ideas here?
Edit: I use norwegian keyboard layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+`<`> for "<",
or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+`>` for ">".

If this doesn't work, you may fallback to these keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
  for Less Than (`<`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
  for Greater Than (`>`)

You may also use a keyboard macro product like
[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to assign any keyboard combination you like to these two
characters.

Comment: Thanks, none of the combinations worked, only if I switch to US layout. I got autohotkey to work in combination with Alt-Gr though :)

Answer (score 2):

The layout on Cepter Cosmo TKL is close to a ISO keyboard and it seems to combine ISO-UK and ISO-Pan-Nordic keyboards by having the legends for both ISO-UK and ISO-Pan-Nordic (combining Norwegian/Danish/Swedish-Finnish) layouts on the keys where the layouts differ from each other. The legends ,< and .> on your keyboard are for the UK layout, while the dimmer legends ,; and .: below them on the same keys are for the pan-Nordic layout.

But. The Left Shift is a departure from the ISO layout: the keyboard has the long Left Shift of US (ANSI) layout instead of having a shorter Left Shift and an extra key between Left Shift and Z. So your keyboard is kind of half ANSI half ISO and it is missing that specific key next to Left Shift which is the <> key on the Norwegian layout.

It is a very peculiar choice from the manufacturer to do the UK/Nordic ISO layout with the extra letters but go with 104 keys of ANSI layout instead of 105 keys of proper ISO layout.

[Cepter Cosmo TKL layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bNLs.jpg)

[difference of 104 key ANSI and 105 key ISO layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfWwd.png)